# Android/JVM difference in RSA decryption

Tags: java, android, rsa

I am trying to decrypt a String, that I have encrypted elsewhere. Here is my code:

```
private void test() {

    try {
        String stringMessage="Sf3O7Lr2+WN5szGyLejL3CjuBRZtQ72+ZBmgVTgWnatQZxUElzaBqFa1p0SVBqe9VWVxCxdEkejMVtDGEr0UJSVSK8EB/fPI6v8JE8dIu0JN0mMs4xlowhITy0tQR+1pcBtDFjzOl33xxQcq5JuPezxRDxFIp+IVkD8FdpqlttEKf2Tvqw9tqsdgiBKb5xDvKrkIDQXdLBh1gbAVZDSJYGHRkcOA8vz2ty/PeooKkfDK6IOn7KBwOBgSRgQr/MLBF3Xk2vRWgVGRh/fRkzu21EWo99Q5moWKxWl3HW/bbgTBQTb097XP3NTID9kSPhCfL0BEfBxonuNse5GBoeRnCw==";
        //Convert String back to Byte[] and decrpt
        byte[] byteMessage = Base64.decodeBase64(stringMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("ENCRYPTED MESSAGE byte Length: "+byteMessage.length);

        String decryptedMsg = decryptString(byteMessage, loadCASPrivateKey());
        System.out.println(decryptedMsg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}

private static String decryptString(byte[] message, Key privateKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(message);
    return new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
}

private PrivateKey loadCASPrivateKey() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/keys/app-private.key" );
    if (is == null) {
        System.out.println("NULL");
    }
    byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) 2000];
    is.read(encodedPrivateKey);
    is.close();

    // Generate KeyPair.
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

    return privateKey;

}
```

This works 100% how I would like it to under my desktop JVM, however when I run it in the Android emulator I get:

> 04-24 22:42:21.011: I/System.out(1041):
>     ��k���_��*�ݣ���93|@0�̍4�y)��Q�k�;*A����e�`#��A�
>   �oiu:�����W5@$�w�j��`uS�R�Ocxٰ&����l
>   �w'/�d�8uA��ؔ�{�4$�U�0��{Ԑ��t!9��n��
>   ��a��'Jdt2�t�T�D��k+k�;������ ����GF��\�rڼ��>]�y+^w�<��
>   ��'E{�8R]�ZHyu��ζ��軟�ށ掱�{�A�#ȟ�

I assume my problem is down to encoding, but I've spent all day trying to work out what and am really stumped.

The string is originally encrypted using:

```
private void test() {
    String message="22223334490384903432221";
try {
    //Encrypt message
    byte[] encryptedMsg = Base64.encodeBase64(encryptString(message, temp.loadCASPublicKey()));
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        return;
}

}

private static byte[] encryptString(String message, Key publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));     
    return cipherData;
}
```

Comment: Don't use defaults. They can be different on different platforms. `Cipher.getInstance()` takes a string argument consisting of *algorithm/mode/padding*. Your are only supplying *algorithm* and are getting defaults for the other two.

Comment: Also, you need to show the `encryptString` method so we can compare it to your `decryptString` method.

Comment: @GregS - Thanks. I have added the encryptString part. I'll look into the Cipher.getInstance, I didn't realise it took more parts.

Comment: @GregS - I have looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#AppA and tried "RSA/NONE/NoPadding". But I get a NoSuchAlgorithmException.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for the pointer. Added a security provider, and then declared the algorithm/mode/padding correctly. :)

Comment: So it now works? If you don't mind, can you please post the working code as an answer? It is acceptable to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to GregS's help in the comments. This is the solution that worked for me.

```
private void test() {

            try {
                String stringMessage="GEQRpAPA577ks/QveudNkk7H9DjItKGLDYW6xhH1YJGabCVzrkejkBh6S+APwEXxB84UV/q0sO5rqkgXWONJQ8CoMTfqXtUkAAwkYHSc86eGewkM8WpctA0AyNVFonOxDCXm84Uq8JRMzqskSH5VXHmMxvHIvpFgdhmt9Ir0cKWzoLsuvgfY9hfypfEyBXGZcoptQeKhsZxRGIlxbXhrFl/LqhC+F6vYtZ/j5pv2LUP38wh2rTCKnAQ+xvC+7wn5SVzt/Wbr/q7GjCoJuU9uFHQSS49KQDt+BzJL2XNwAMmdbC+XHYkEBBWxVSS+0hdSQxoaKVZZJk4hTnHwQlBAkw==";
                //Convert String back to Byte[] and decrpt
                byte[] byteMessage = Base64.decodeBase64(stringMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                System.out.println("ENCRYPTED MESSAGE byte Length: "+byteMessage.length);

                String decryptedMsg = decryptString(byteMessage, loadCASPrivateKey());
                System.out.println(decryptedMsg);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }

        private static String decryptString(byte[] message, Key privateKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException {
            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding","BC");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

            byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(message);
            return new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
        }

        private PrivateKey loadCASPrivateKey() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/keys/app-private.key" );
            if (is == null) {
                System.out.println("NULL");
            }
            byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) 1216];
            is.read(encodedPrivateKey);
            is.close();

            // Generate KeyPair.
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

            return privateKey;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your feeding the `KeyFactory` garbage since you are reading into a 2000 byte array, and your key is probably something like 128 (1024 bits) or 256 (2048 bits) bytes long. Additionally, you shouldn't really use RSA for encryption directly: there are security issues with this the data size you can encrypt is limited by the RSA key size.

Comment: What would you suggest I replace the byte array with? Would the way it feeds into KeyFactory differ between the JVM and Android? I am using the RSA to encrypt a fixed length random hash. Thanks.

Comment: Read the stream and only use as many bytes as there are in file/asset.  Not sure what you are trying to do, but encrypting a hash is generally referred as 'signing' and is done with the private key and verified with the public one.

Comment: What JCE provider and Java version are you using on the desktop? Try to find what RSA Ciphers are supported by listing all algorithms