# java.crypto different output on mac/linux JVM & Android 2.2 to Android 2.3

Tags: android, encryption

The following code, decrypts the string as expected on the JVM on my laptop, my server and in Android v2.2. However, if I use exactly the same code on Android 2.3 I get an incorrect output. I thought it may be due to the defaults on one of the functions being different, but I am pretty sure I am not using any defaults...

```
    private void test() {

        try {
            String stringMessage="GEQRpAPA577ks/QveudNkk7H9DjItKGLDYW6xhH1YJGabCVzrkejkBh6S+APwEXxB84UV/q0sO5rqkgXWONJQ8CoMTfqXtUkAAwkYHSc86eGewkM8WpctA0AyNVFonOxDCXm84Uq8JRMzqskSH5VXHmMxvHIvpFgdhmt9Ir0cKWzoLsuvgfY9hfypfEyBXGZcoptQeKhsZxRGIlxbXhrFl/LqhC+F6vYtZ/j5pv2LUP38wh2rTCKnAQ+xvC+7wn5SVzt/Wbr/q7GjCoJuU9uFHQSS49KQDt+BzJL2XNwAMmdbC+XHYkEBBWxVSS+0hdSQxoaKVZZJk4hTnHwQlBAkw==";
            //Convert String back to Byte[] and decrpt
            byte[] byteMessage = Base64.decodeBase64(stringMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("ENCRYPTED MESSAGE byte Length: "+byteMessage.length);

            String decryptedMsg = decryptString(byteMessage, loadCASPrivateKey());
            System.out.println(decryptedMsg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    private static String decryptString(byte[] message, Key privateKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding","BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(message);
        return new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
    }

    private PrivateKey loadCASPrivateKey() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/keys/app-private.key" );
        if (is == null) {
            System.out.println("NULL");
        }
        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) 1216];
        is.read(encodedPrivateKey);
        is.close();

        // Generate KeyPair.
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        return privateKey;

    }
```

Output:

> 04-28 15:00:05.969: I/System.out(677):
>   � �;��bW�Q<�tz.�c4Ă핆�Q�"��    6����"bW    �k!�

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306560/android-jvm-difference-in-rsa-decryption) is the related earlier question.

Comment: @GregS Not sure if its the same problem or not as I fixed the earlier problem. I guess it makes sense to have a link between the two though.

Comment: There are some issues with Bouncy Castle on Android. Have you tried Spongy Castle instead? See: https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle

Comment: @rossum: I don't see any bouncycastle classes being explicitly used here. Are you suggesting to explicitly request the Spongycastle provider in the getInstance() methods? That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I have removed the bouncy castle jar and replaced it with the spongy castle one. I then replaced org.bouncycastle with org.spongycastle throughout but I still have the same problem.

Comment: And you changed the getInstance() methods to use "SC" instead of "BC"? Including KeyFactory?

Comment: Yes, still the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: For debugging purposes print out the resulting bytes as hex encoded. Printing out random characters doesn't tell us much.